# mvvm pattern in this style of coding is meanless?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have developed my own project with MVC pattern and trying to convert to MVVM pattern, but sometimes I think its getting worse and meanless.

This is a part of my code. I have controller, model and one view-model like below:

```
struct FAQ: Mappable {        
    var id: String?
    var question: String?
    var answer: String?
    var datalist: [FAQ]?
    //var datalist: [Any]?

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        question <- map["question"]
        answer <- map["answer"]
        datalist <- map["data"]
    }
}

class learningViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var faqLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var learningLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uiviewHeader: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barRight: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var barLeft: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backImage: UIImageView!

    var learningRequestSession: URLSessionDataTask?
    let address = Domains.address
    var objectData = faqViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        objectData.faqFunc {
            self.setup()
        }
        setup()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectData.objectData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "faqCell", for: indexPath) as! customViewCellTableViewCell

        //cell.faqIcon.image = UIImage(named: "question")
        cell.faqTitle.text = objectData.objectData[indexPath.row].question
        cell.faqBody.text = objectData.objectData[indexPath.row].answer

        return cell            
    }
...
}
```

and this is view-model class:

```
class faqViewModel {
    var objectData = [FAQ]()

    init(faq: [FAQ]) {
        self.objectData = faq
    }

    init() {}

    func faqFunc(complition: @escaping () -> () ) {        
        let url = URL(string: "\(address)faq/getdata")
        print(url!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: .mutableContainers) as Any

                    let mapper = Mapper<FAQ>().map(JSONObject: json)

                    self.objectData = (mapper?.datalist.map({ $0}))!
                } catch {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

faqFunc function used to be in controller class in MVC pattern.

I have moved it to view-model in this pattern. So I feel I am doing it wrong or MVC was better...!

Comment: What is 'measless'?

Comment: my mistake . mean-less

Answer (score 2):

Some of MVC problems are well described in [Dave DeLongs blog](https://davedelong.com/blog/2017/11/06/a-better-mvc-part-1-the-problems/).

I agree with him, that MVC, **in some cases** may lead to:

1. **M**assive **V**iew **C**ontrollers (View logic, business logic and networking are often placed in `*ViewController` classes which grow, sometimes enormously.
2. Incapsulation violation (e. g. Passing data to `ViewController` in segue and so on)
3. Testability. MVC usually requires writing integration tests, which are hard to maintain and require very good knowledge of `UIKit`

### MVVM

It is worth of saying, that MVVM is basically a fancy MVC.

MVVM is an attempt to address some flaws of the MVC pattern. It improves [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), makes logic somehow clearer. No more massive view controllers (with proper usage). IMHO, the best benefit of the MVVM is **Testability**. Now we have `ViewModel`, object that contains all view-related data. So writing tests doesn't require integration testing anymore. But using MVVM usually connected to some kind of reactive programming. Which, itself, has hidden pitfalls and steep learning curve.

### MVVM Pros

1. Better testability
2. Better separation of concerns
3. Getting rid of Massive View Controllers
4. It kinda fits CocoaTouch MVC paradigm

There's more, I guess

### MVVM Cons

1. Using reactive frameworks requires "mindset" change and, as a result - steep learning curve
2. It is easy to get model and view out of sync
3. Easy to make mistake in observing logic

And more

### Conclusions

MVVM is a nice tool which, when used properly, fixes some MVC flaws and gives production benefits. MVVM requires some effort and best practices learning. But, before diving into it I suggest to read [Dave DeLongs blog series "A better MVC"](https://davedelong.com/blog/2017/11/06/a-better-mvc-part-1-the-problems/) and remember, that MVC is a native Apple pattern, and by implementing it you stay "safe" from big surprises when SDK is updated.

**P.S.** I am a big fan of **proper** MVVM usage, but improper usage frightens me sometimes.

Comment: thanks for your great tips. do you suggest mvvm pattern for big projects? isn't two much file ?

Comment: It depends on many factors and project scale is far not the only factor that determines application design solutions. In my opinion there is no simple answer to this question. I think one should use the architecture he understands in depth. Another thing to remember that if architecture makes your life not easier but worse, it is a bad architecture.

Answer (score 1):

View model is a kind mini model for used within a view. So you bind view attributes to it and mange changes in each of them:

View changed -> view-model updates

View-Model changed -> view updates

The `faqViewModel` class you wrote is a kind of APIRequestLoader and not belongs to view-model. For more information, I suggest you to do some research about `Clean Swift Architecture` and `Swift Viper Architecture` and if you want to learn more about how to decouple network request from other parts of the app, [This WWDC 2018 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/417/) is a good option to watch.

Comment: thanks for helping.you are saying view-model only binds the view ? and no network request and calculation in it right ? I do my network request in controller then with view-model update the view?? so I should change my code this way : put my network request inside controller and move my tableView update to View-model.right ?

Comment: View-model has two words. View -> UI and Model -> the model behind the view (not the model behind the entire application!). And remember, model is not just a data set. Imagine you what to describe your app without saying how its look like. (No buttons to touch, No fields for input, etc.) Anything you'll say in this phase will be live in the model! Not the controller (Since MVVM has not Controller). But you can separate network layer in a mini MVC and interact with it. And please don't forget to mark right answer to your question as accepted answer.